# Swift - Get Day of Week Locale

Tags: swift

how do i get a day of week from tomorrow until day before today. For example if today is monday i need to get the day Tuesday, Wednesday, until Sunday. Can someone please guide me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: mind telling me why the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do it, depending on what format you want the output. Assuming you want an array of integers in sequence, you could use:

```
let today = Date()
let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let dateComponents = gregorian.dateComponents([.weekday], from: today)
let todaysWeekday = dateComponents.weekday!
var otherWeekdays: [Int] = []
for i in 1...6 {
    otherWeekdays.append((todaysWeekday - 1 + i) % 7 + 1)
}
// assuming today = 2 (Monday), otherWeekdays will contain [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]
```

If you also want an array of strings containing the names of the days, you could do a simple lookup if you don't care about localisation.

```
let weekdayNames = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
let otherWeekdayStrings = otherWeekdays.map({weekdayNames[$0 - 1]})
// otherweekdayStrings will contain ["Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

If robust localisation is required and you only want the strings, you can use a DateFormatter and do something like this:

```
let today = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
var otherweekdayStrings: [String] = []
for i in 1...6 {
    let timeIntervalToAdd = TimeInterval(i * 86400)
    otherweekdayStrings.append(formatter.string(from: today.addingTimeInterval(timeIntervalToAdd)))
}
// Same output as previous
```